# Non-commutativity of certain Hopf spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How do one prove (or disprove) that $\Omega S^{2}$ and $\Omega(S^{2} \vee S^{2})$ are non commutative Hopf spaces?

I thought this is a question for math.stackexchange, but not many people even viewed that question. Seems like it should be easy but right now I have no idea how to do it. Any hint?

Definition: If $X$ is commutative Hopf space if, for the multiplication $
\mu $ there is a homotopy between $ H: \mu \simeq \mu \circ T $, where $T : X \times X \to X \times X$ is the switch map.

Clarification: When I say multiplication, I mean multiplication induced by the loop structure. On $\Omega S^{2}$ there is another multiplication which is induced by multiplication on $S^{1}$ as $\Omega S^{2} = \Omega \Sigma S^{1} $ ( This is of course commutative).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310824/non-commutativity-of-hopf-space

Here is my question in math.stackexchange.com. One may put the answer wherever it is appropriate

Comment: Your non-commutative Hopf algebras look like topological spaces.

Comment: Please use a tag with a two-letter prefix (instead of creating one without) if (and only if!) they already exist. [The complete list is given right below the field where you enter the tag.]

Comment: On MSE you talk of H-spaces, here you talk of Hopf algebras. These are not strictly speaking the same thing. What is it you actually mean to ask?

Comment: Sorry, I meant spaces and I changed the title!

Comment: May you also change the question? BTW all loop spaces are H-spaces, is you point the non-commutative character of these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us run the Serre SS for homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients for the fibration

$\Omega(S^{2} \vee S^{2}) \to * \to S^{2} \vee S^{2}$

Let $x,y \in H_{2}(S^{2} \vee S^{2})$ be the generators. Since these guys has to die, there exists $x_{1}, y_{1} \in H_{1}(\Omega(S^{2} \vee S^{2}))$ which are hit by $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Notice that there are $4$ terms at $E^{2}_{2,1}$ namely $x_{1}x, y_{1}x, x_{1}y, y_{1}y$.

$d_{2}(x_{1}y) = x_{1}y_{1}$ and $ d_{2}(y_{1}x) =y_{1}x_{1} $.

So $x_{1}y + y_{1}x$ survives if $x_{1}y_{1} = y_{1}x_{1}$ and never dies. Which is a contradiction.

this shows that in homology the elements $x_{1},y_{1}$ do not commute. So $\Omega(S^{2} \vee S^{2})$ is not a commutative Hopf space.

I think this is correct. But the case of $\Omega S^{2}$ still remains unanswered.

Edit: The complete answer is given by Justin in the comments below.

Comment: If $X$ is a space, the multiplication in $\Omega(X)$ is the concatenation of paths, and this is a commutative operation iff $\Omega(X)$ has exactly one point. Probably you were not asking something which has this as answer, but then I do not understand your question.

Comment: To start with I have to admit that the situation is very blurry to me at this moment. But I do mean multiplication by concatenation, the usual multiplication on a loop space, at least thats the multiplication I was thinking of. I do not understand what you mean when you say "exactly one point". 

Comment: I do not know if I am hitting the right cord, but what I mean by commutative hopf algebra is that I have a homotopy between 
$H: \mu \simeq \mu \circ T$, where $T: \Omega(X) \times \Omega(X) \to \Omega(X) \times \Omega(X) $ is the switch map. 

Comment: It would then be useful to add that information to the body of the question.

Comment: In general, if $\tilde H_*(X, R)$ is free then $H_*(\Omega \Sigma X, R)$ is a tensor algebra on $\tilde H_*(X,R)$, and tensor algebras are not commutative. You can prove this using your Serre SS. With $X = S^1$ and $X = S^1 \vee S^1$ you get your result. Hi Prasit!

Comment: Edit: in the above I should specify that tensor algebras are not commutative provided the generators are more than one dimensional, or in odd degree. Remember, to be commutative, odd degree elements must satisfy $2x^2 = 0$. 

Comment: You mean $R$ the real numbers?

Comment: Hey Justin!! ( So happy to find you here). This completes the proof. One remark though, One do not need to use Serre SS. I would say it follows by construction, James construction!

Comment: $R$ is an arbitrary ring, but $R=\mathbb R$ suffices as does $R= \mathbb Z$. And yes, the James construction works if you already know about it (which you do).